# Getting Error "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object"

Tags: python, byte, typeerror

I am Using Python3 and in my code getting the following error. trying to download pdf and storing in local directory

```
r_l = 'https://www.ccc.com'
class Data:

    def getlk(self, url):
        all_links = []
        page = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
        for href in soup.find_all(class_='omrlist'):
            all_links.append(root_url + href.find('a').get('href'))
        return all_links

    def getmth_lk(self, ylk):
        rpLk = []
        for url in ylk:
            links = self.getlk(url)
            reportLinks.append(links)


            for url_ in links:
                if ".pdf" in url_:
                    if "Annual" not in url_:
                        lastindex = url_.rfind('/')
                        strlen = len(url_)
                        filename = url_[lastindex:strlen].replace("/", "")

                        file = pathlib.Path('/home/' + filename)
                        if not file.exists():
                            urllib.request.urlretrieve(rpLk, str(filename))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = Data()
    yLk = obj.getlk(r_l + '/oil/reports/')
    mth_lk = obj.getmth_lk(yLk)
```

I tried the above code but the error is comming

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dwnpdf-to-dir.py", line 248, in <module>
    mth_lk = obj.getmth_lk(yLk)
  File "/home/dwnpdf-to-dir.py", line 228, in getmth_lk
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(rpLk, str(filename))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 186, in urlretrieve
    url_type, path = splittype(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/parse.py", line 861, in splittype
    match = _typeprog.match(url)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

the above error is coming So, pleas guide me to overcome from this error

Answer (score 0):

Well as said in the error, `urlretrieve` takes as first positional argument a `string or bytes-like object`. However `rpLk` is a list.

Should not you rather pass `url_` as an argument?

You're trying to download the file if you haven't already? I think you should be using `urllib.request.urlopen` instead.

Comment: I tried what you mention but the following error is comming.. Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/dwnpdf-to-dir.py", line 253, in <module> mth_lk = obj.getmth_lk(yLk) File "/home/dwnpdf-to-dir.py", line 233, in getmth_lk urllib.request.urlopen(rpLk, str(filename)) File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 163, in urlopen return opener.open(url, data, timeout) File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 455, in open req.data = data AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'data'

Comment: Read the whole answer. `rpLk` is still a list. I said to try passing `url_` instead